# How to determine the source of a GeoServer layer?

Tags: geoserver

How can I determine the source of an existing layer in GeoServer?

To illustrate, I have a Data Store pointing to a PostgreSQL database, and I Publish a table in this PG database to create a GeoServer layer.

The layer creation page shows the Data Store and PG table name, but I rename the layer so that the layer name no longer matches the PG table name:

[image]

After the layer has been published, reopening the layer's page in GeoServer no longer references the actual table name in PostgreSQL:

[image]

How can I trace the fact that the layer `blah` is sourced from the table `aus_supplychain_motor_webmap_qaa_clms`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The information is available in the feature type. While I haven't found it using the UI, you can use the REST interface to see it:

```
http://localhost/geoserver/rest/workspaces/<workspaceName>/datastores/<DataStoreName>/featuretypes/<layerName>.xml
```

ex: `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/odltest/datastores/DBcan/featuretypes/roads_test.xml`

Alternatively, you can browse to `/<geoserver_data>/workspaces/<workspacename>/<store name>/<layer name>` and read the file `featuretype.xml`, specificaly the field `<nativeName>`
ex:

```
<featureType>
  <id>FeatureTypeInfoImpl--1e400972:15f5b3e83e0:-7ffd</id>
  <name>roads_test</name>
  <nativeName>roads</nativeName>
[...]
```